# Automatically populate a column if there is a date?

Tags: sql, oracle

The requirement states that I should automatically populate a column that may or may not contain a date, if there is a date then the output should be a "Y" and if not "N". I don't know where to start. So I need a sql query to produce this. I basically want a sql query that changes the reference column to the new column. Lets assume the table name is NewTable.

---

```
| **reference column** | 

| 08/10/2015    |   
    Null               (NO DATE)  
| 08/10/2015    |      
| 08/12/2015    |  
| 07/10/2015  
     Null              (NO DATE)        
| 09/17/2015    |
```

I want the reference column to change into this new column through a sql query.

```
| **new column** | 

 Y      
 N   
 Y  
 Y   
 Y    
 N   
 Y
```

Comment: Sorry, I am new to stackoverflow I updated the post

Comment: why do you need a NEW column to store what is already in another columN? `select ... if referencecol is null is then 'n' else 'y' endif as newcolumn`

Comment: I technically want a sql query that changes the reference columns into the new column. ( if that makes sense)

Comment: yes, but why a whole new column? that's a waste of space to replicate data that's already present elsewhere, and then forces you to either manually maintain the state of that new column, or litter the table with triggers to do the maintenance for you. either way, it's a lot of extra work for basically doing what you can already do WITHOUT changing the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a `case` statement.

```
select submission, 
case when submission is not null then 'Y' else 'N' end as changes
from returntable;
```

Comment: I tried this and I got an error, (Here are the real table names):

select submission
case when submission is not null then 'Y' else 'N' as Changes
from returntable;

I got the error Error at line 2
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: you should have a `,` after `submission` in your query

Comment: omfg, I love you VKP you are the real mvp, one more question is there any way to hide the submissions columna nd only display the Y's and N's?

Comment: you should simply exclude it from the `select` clause.

Comment: Thanks so much, Im pretty new to coding and this is some what advance for me, but thanks so much you've have simply increased my knowledge in this area

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into creating a trigger? Does that meet your requirement?

Examples: 
http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/after_insert.php